# If a function $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f'$ is bounded, then $f$ is Riemann integrable

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Actually if a function is differentiable then it is continuous which implies that it is Riemann integrable. Then why is there a need of extra point "it's derivative is bounded."

Comment: So $f$ is continuous but $f'$ may not be.   When they say here "it is Riemann integrable, I think they mean $f'$.

Answer (score 0):

Simple counterexample why bounded derivative is needed: $f(x)=\frac1x$ on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want it to be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.  But it is **not** known to be continuous
 on $[a,b]$, just on $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous functions are only Riemman-integrable if they are bounded. This condition is necessary for it being bounded, since $f$ is differentiable (see Zachary's answer for an counterexample). It's also sufficient (try to estimate the supremum of $f$ with $\sup f'$).